# customize navigator.geolocation bar in html5

Tags: html, geolocation, navigator

is it possible to customize the navigator geolocation bar which is generated by

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      //....
   });
}
```

Right now the bar looks really ugly, and searching in the internet did not bring any results

The bar, where the user is asked if he wants to share his location with an app.

Comment: For security reasons, you will never have any control over any security prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the permission bar, the answer is no.

Comment: Actually, this is probably for the best. If you could change, a malicious person could modify it enough to make it near unreadable or confusing. An end user who doesn't want to share their location may be tricked into allowing it. By having it standardized the UI is *always* going to be consistent.